# Xcode 7 SpriteKit Error with Blocks

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, ios9, xcode7

Does *anybody* know why this won't work anymore in Xcode 7 GM?

I have debugged and verified, but even though the nodes are appearing on the scene, they no longer pass touch events to parent nodes.

Below is a fully working example.  If you replace the default GameScene from the "New Sprite Kit Game" you can reproduce it yourself.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let card = Card(imageNamed: "card_background_blank")
        card.name = "Card"
        let stack = Stack(imageNamed: "stack_background")
        stack.name = "Stack"
        addChild(stack)
        stack.addChild(card)
        card.position = CGPointMake(100,100)
        stack.zPosition = 1
        card.zPosition = 1
        stack.position = CGPointMake(506,428)
        card.userInteractionEnabled = false
        stack.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Touch")
        moveAllCardsAndReturn()
    }
    func moveAllCardsAndReturn () {
        var wait:NSTimeInterval = 1.0
        let waitIncrement:NSTimeInterval = 0.05
        let duration:NSTimeInterval = 0.15
        func removeAndMove(card:Card) {
            let oldParent = card.parent!
            card.removeFromParent()
            addChild(card)
            card.position = CGPointMake(500,48)
            var sequence = [SKAction]()
            sequence.append(SKAction.waitForDuration(wait))
            sequence.append(SKAction.runBlock({
                card.removeFromParent()
                oldParent.addChild(card)
                card.position = CGPointMake(100,100)
            }))
            card.runAction(SKAction.sequence(sequence))
            wait += waitIncrement
        }
        let stack = childNodeWithName("Stack")
        let card = stack?.childNodeWithName("Card")
        removeAndMove(card as! Card)


    }

}

class Stack:SKSpriteNode {
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Stack Touch")
    }
}
class Card:SKSpriteNode {
}
```

What happens is the scene works correctly, but touches no longer pass to the parent node, even though userInteractionEnabled is false for the card and true for the parent node of the card (a Stack:SKSpriteNode)

So, I have updated this with a working test case.  It is a bug, as it works in iOS 8.4 sim, but not in 9 GM.  I have submitted it to apple.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue in a new sample project? That usually helps narrow down the cause of issues like this.

Comment: I updated it with a working project.  If you replace the default GameScene in a new Sprite Kit Game (and add the two required images, stack_background and card_background_blank, you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Seems this bug was present in iOS 7 as well, [see this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726606/swift-1-2-bug-different-behavior-between-ios-7-1-and-8-3-while-removing-sksprit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug.

I have created a tester class to test for the presence of the bug and act accordingly...

Can be found [here](https://github.com/visskiss/SpriteKitBugTester)